# Determine if code is running in specific thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, concurrency, stl

In my application i run background operation using this snippet:

```
m_thread = std::thread(&MyClass::BackOp, this);
```

Sometimes different threads (including `m_thread` itself, possibly) in my application call function `Close()` which waits for background thread to complete its operation:

```
if(m_thread.joinable()) m_thread.join();
```

And this is unsafe behaviour, if i am right, it may cause *deadlock*.

Can i determine in my `Close()` function text, if it is running in my background thread, to skip "joining"?

Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you use synchronisation primitives, like mutex with which you could define some sort of "critical section"?

Comment: Firstly, critical sections/mutex are slow as hell in my nanospeed routines. Secondly, i just don't need it in this question, in my function `Close()` i  only wait for thread to complete. Possibly, this may be executed from any thread in my application, including `m_thread` itself.

Comment: Just a note: `if(m_thread.joinable()) m_thread.join();` could theoretically result in an exception of type `std::system_error` and code `invalid_argument` if, after `m_thread.joinable()` is evaluated but before `m_thread.join()` is executed, `m_thread` finishes executing and is joined by a third thread. Also note that operations on `std::thread` objects are not synchronized, so this whole business of different threads accessing the same `m_thread` is inherently risky.

Comment: @bogdan so isn't where any solution to safely call `join()` without `try..catch`..?

Comment: Even if catching exceptions, there are no guarantees with your code. It's difficult to give a solution without knowing what your exact requirements are for the semantics of `Close()` in the presence of multiple threads (that's a separate question). If you really want several threads to wait concurrently for the background thread to finish, you'll need a proper synchronization mechanism to do that reliably - a [`std::condition_variable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) or a [`std::shared_future`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_future), for example.

Comment: If you actually only want one thread to wait, and, once one is waiting, the others can just skip, then an [`std::atomic_flag`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_flag) may be enough, and it's guaranteed to be pretty much the fastest you can get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can i determine in my `Close()` function if it is running in my background thread, to skip "joining"?

Yes, you can use the [`std::this_thread::get_id()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/get_id) function and compare with `m_thread.get_id()` to determine if the routine runs within the same `std::thread` instance.

Comment: What makes you think `joinable()` will not return true if called on the current thread of execution?

Comment: @Joker `m_thread.join();`, however, will throw an exception if `m_thread` is the current thread of execution - an `std::system_error` with a code `resource_deadlock_would_occur` - so you won't have deadlock.

Comment: @bogdan How, could that routine actually execute from within the thread, if the thread has already finished execution, to make it return `true`?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ `m_thread` operation itself is a long-term process which may decide to stop itself with shared `Close()` function described in my question. It's pretty usual case. Or you don't understand threading?

Comment: @Joker Sorry, I was wrong about `joinable()`. Will remove that from the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to use [std::this_thread::get_id](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/get_id) and compare its result to the result of [std::thread::get_id](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/get_id) (of your "background" thread). Or have some thread local variables (perhaps storing these at start of thread, etc.).

Comment: Correct, although, sharing variables across several threads **is not safe** due to heap caching.

Answer (score -4):

You should use `if(m_thread.joinable()) m_thread.join();`. Never heard that it is unsafe.

Comment: What if `Close()` called within `m_thread` context? It will join for itself and this should be dealock?

Comment: @Joker According to standard, 30.3.1.5 thread members, `join` requires thread to be 'joinable' and will detect situation when `this->get_id() == std::this_thread::get_id()` - will throw an exception meaning `resource_deadlock_would_occur`